# Автоматизация заполнения форм программы

Tags: python, кодировка, форма

Имеется скрипт, результатом выполнения которого являются текстовые значения, разделенные табуляцией:
'Привет    мир    !' ('Привет\tмир\t!').
Также имеется программа с полями ввода, например, такая:

```
import tkinter

w = tkinter.Tk()
ent1 = tkinter.Entry()
ent1.pack()
ent2 = tkinter.Entry()
ent2.pack()
ent3 = tkinter.Entry()
ent3.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

Результат работы первого скрипта отправляется в буфер обмена.
Далее курсор устанавливается в первое поле ввода программы.
Возможно ли сделать, чтобы первое значение появилось в первой ячейке, второе - во второй, третье - в третей? При этом программу с ячейками трогать нельзя.

Первое, на что обратил внимание - это что перемещаться по ячейкам программы можно при помощи кнопки TAB. Опробовал следующее:

1. Разделение текстовых значений в первом скрипте табуляцией не помогло.
2. Нашел библиотеку PyAutoGUI (автоматизирует нажимание кнопок), написал скрипт, повесил его на горячую клавишу при помощи программы Mkey:

```
import pyautogui
import win32clipboard

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
s = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
my_list = s.split('\t')
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    pyautogui.typewrite(my_list[i])
    pyautogui.press('tab')
```

однако, в этом случае русские буквы не пропечатываются.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо PyAutoGUI надо использовать модуль keyboard, методы для нажатия кнопки и печатания текста называются так же.